I have a dashboard view in django in which it has to show data of a user and other models linked to it. Its not showing the other model's data
I want that when the user logs in to the app, it should get all the details after he adds the details. like wallets name, api keys, its username etc. but its neither showing error nor it prints the data.
THis is the wallet (2nd) model code
class Wallet(models.Model):

    
    owner = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='wallets', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    api_key = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=False, validators=[MinLengthValidator(64)])
    secret_key = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=False, validators=[MinLengthValidator(64)])
    date_connected = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.wallet_type

this is the User's model
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    @property
    def getter_signal_limit(self):
        return self.signal_limit

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
    webhook_url = serializers.SerializerMethodField()  
    signal_limit = models.IntegerField(default=50, validators=[MinValueValidator(1)])
    signals_used = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    plan = models.CharField(max_length=12, choices=(
        ('Basic', 'Basic'), ('standard', 'Standard'), ('premium', 'Premium'), ('platinum', 'Platinum')),
                            default='Basic')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    timezone = timezone.get_current_timezone()

this is the view that I'm using
class DashboardView1(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = 'dashboard.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

        # Fetch the User instance based on the username
        user = User.objects.get(username='hasnain')

        # Fetch the UserProfile associated with the user
        user_profile = UserProfile.objects.get(user=user)

        # Fetch wallets and signals associated with the user
        wallets = Wallet.objects.filter(owner=user_profile)
        signals = Signal.objects.filter(owner=user_profile)

        context['user_profile'] = user_profile
        context['wallets'] = wallets
        context['signals'] = signals
        return context

this is the serializer's code
class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = '__all__'
        
    def create(self, validated_data):
        user_data = validated_data.pop('user')
        user = UserSerializer.create(**user_data)
        user_profile = UserProfile.objects.create(user=user, **validated_data)
        return user_profile


this is the html code
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Dashboard</title>
    <!-- Add your CSS stylesheets or links to frameworks here -->
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Welcome, {{ user_profile.user.username }}</h1>
        <h1>Email: {{ user_profile.user.email }}</h1>
        
        <!-- Add any other user-related information here -->
    </header>

    <section>
        <h2>Plan:</h2>
        <p> {{ user_profile.plan }}</p>
        <br>
        <h2>Wallets1</h2>
        <ul>
            
            {% for wallets in wallet %}
            <li> wallet name {{ wallet.exchange_name }} - Type: {{ wallet.wallet_type }}</li>
            <li> api key {{ wallet.api_key }}</li>
            <li> secret key {{ wallet.secret_key }}</li>
            <li> date connected {{ wallet.date_connected }}</li>
            <!-- Display other wallet details as needed -->
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </section>
    
    <section>
    <h2>Wallets</h2>
    <ul>
        {% for wallet in wallets %}
            <li> Wallet name {{ wallet.exchange_name }} - Type: {{ wallet.wallet_type }}</li>
            <li> API key {{ wallet.api_key }}</li>
            <li> Date connected {{ wallet.date_connected }}</li>
            <!-- Display other wallet details as needed -->
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</section>
    
        <br>
        <br>
        
    <!-- Add more sections or elements as necessary -->

    <footer>
        <!-- Add footer content if needed -->
    </footer>

    <!-- Add your JavaScript files or links to frameworks here -->
</body>
</html>


this is the image of the result. (data is blurred)
Image
i have tried using
Wallet.objects.filter(owner=user_profile)
and
Wallet.objects.get(owner=user_profile) but none of them is working

Taking a closer look at your codes, I believe the error is coming from your Template file, based on how you are iterating the queryset loops from your wallets as you called in the dict, context["wallets"] and please ensure you use the ListView not TemplateView.
Corrected Template Section of your code:
Update the "Wallets1" section in your template like this:
   <section>
       <h2>Wallets1</h2>
       <ul>
           {% for wallet in wallets %} <!-- not for wallets in wallet -->
               <li>Wallet name {{ wallet.exchange_name }} - Type: {{ wallet.wallet_type }}</li>
               <li>API key {{ wallet.api_key }}</li>
               <li>Secret key {{ wallet.secret_key }}</li>
               <li>Date connected {{ wallet.date_connected }}</li>
               <!-- Display other wallet details as needed -->
           {% endfor %}
       </ul>
   </section>

However, to make your user profile filtering much more dynamic instead of filtering a static username instance named  hasnain like you did
here => user = User.objects.get(username='hasnain'), get the logged in username parameter directly from the request user.username.
So, here is the updated version of your View code:
    template_name = 'dashboard.html'
    queryset = Wallet.objects.all()

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(DashboardView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        # Fetch the User instance based on the username
        username = self.request.user.username
        user = User.objects.get(username=username)
        # please note - you can actually get the username from user.username in your template if you want, again I discovered that you commented out username instance (field) in your userprofile, so using user.username here makes no sense.

        # Fetch the UserProfile associated with the user
 
        user_profile = UserProfile.objects.get(user=user)

        # Fetch wallets and signals associated with the user
        wallets = Wallet.objects.filter(owner=user_profile)
        signals = Signal.objects.filter(owner=user_profile)

        context['user_profile'] = user_profile
        context['wallets'] = wallets
        context['signals'] = signals
        return context

simplified version of the get_context_data of your code above is (so, use anyone you like), but this last one is more cleaner imo:

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(DashboardView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        # Fetch the User instance based on userprofile
        user_profile = self.request.user.userprofile

        # Fetch wallets and signals associated with the user
        wallets = Wallet.objects.filter(owner=user_profile)
        signals = Signal.objects.filter(owner=user_profile)

        context['user_profile'] = user_profile
        context['wallets'] = wallets
        context['signals'] = signals
        return context

Goodluck

thanks for the help. can i have your any social media if you are willing to help me in future?
thanks again for the detailed answer, it helped me a lot.

I am glad that I could be of help to sort out your challenge mate, kindly tick it good as already answered the question, that would mean a lot for our Django/Python community in case anyone has a similar issue like yours, by following your title it will answer the person's question in the future. For my social media accounts you asked for here are my Linkedin and Github. Feel free to chat me up anytime mate.

and once i was trying to get the user details but when i went to the dashboard it said that the user 'xyz' must be a User instance. and i was sending it a user. i didn't get that error message, can you elaborate it for me?

I believe this error came up based on the user model instance, perhaps that is not logged in to access the wallet as the owner. So, instead of directly referring to User as you'd in the Dashboard view, use django.contrib.auth.get_user_model(). You can just import it from django.contrib app. This method returns the currently active user model – either the custom user model if one is specified or the default User model.
For example, replace User.objects.get(username='xyz') with get_user_model().objects.get(username='xyz')

You can also checkout the updated version of the simplified code. Either of the two should work.

ok thanks, i'll try. I have followed you in linkedin with the id name "hasnain'. please follow back so we can keep in touch

there is another question i posted. can you please help me with that?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78511650/when-i-try-to-send-a-post-request-to-a-view-using-the-rest-framework-api-view
