when i try to send a post request to a view using the rest framework @api_view(['POST'). it shows this error and i don't know why
this is the view which i'm using to recieve the post data. I have tried using csrf token in the postman, and used @csrf_exempt. but it still showing this error. All I want that when the secret or some other variable is send, it should find the Bot object through it and with the bot it should get all the data of the wallet using serializers.
@csrf_exempt
@permission_classes([AllowAny])
@api_view(['POST', 'GET'])
def get_alert_message(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        try:
            data = json.loads(request.body)
            print(data)
            secret = data.get['secret']
            max_lag = data.get['max_lag']
            timestamp = data.get['timestamp']
            bot = Bot.objects.get(secret=secret).get_queryset()
            bot_data = BotSerializer(Bot=bot).data
            wallet = Wallet.objects.filter(bot=bot)

this is in the setting.py file. its the rest framework section
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    # Use Django's standard `django.contrib.auth` permissions,
    # or allow read-only access for unauthenticated users.
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.PageNumberPagination',
    'PAGE_SIZE': 10,
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.DjangoModelPermissionsOrAnonReadOnly',
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',

    ],
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.renderers.StaticHTMLRenderer'
    ]
}

this is the error which is shown whether i use the browser or the postman.
AssertionError at /get_message/

Cannot apply DjangoModelPermissionsOrAnonReadOnly on a view that does not set `.queryset` or have a `.get_queryset()` method.

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/get_message/
Django Version:     4.2.11
Exception Type:     AssertionError
Exception Value:    

Cannot apply DjangoModelPermissionsOrAnonReadOnly on a view that does not set `.queryset` or have a `.get_queryset()` method.

i have tried csrf exempt. and tried commenting the        'rest_framework.permissions.DjangoModelPermissionsOrAnonReadOnly', from the settings and it showed tokenn error after that

Hello mate, kindly check out this post, and pay attention to the answers given there - it might help to solve the issue, and If it doesn't then get back to me.  Here

hey, yeah it did the job for me. thanks for the reference. Appreciate it

I am glad that it did the work. Good luck with your project.
